# How to use \dotfill between two columns of a table?

Tags: tables, columns

I would like to use dotted lines (via the `\dotfill` command or equivalent) in a `tabular*` environment so that there are also dots in the space between two columns (like the red dots in the image below) but I can't manage it.

[image]

Here is a MWE (with some unsuccessful attempts) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pfill{\leavevmode\leaders\hb@xt@.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}} l<{\pfill} c}\toprule
    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456\\
    Blah blah & 123456789\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

%\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}} l<{\pfill} @{\pfill} c}\toprule% Does not work
%    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
%    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456\\
%    Blah blah & 123456789\\\bottomrule
%\end{tabular*}

%\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\pfill}} l<{\pfill} c}\toprule% Does not work
%    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
%    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456\\
%    Blah blah & 123456789\\\bottomrule
%\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with package `nicematrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pfill{\leavevmode\leaders\hb@xt@.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{0.6\textwidth}{X<{\pfill}@{}c}
    \toprule
    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456 \\
    Blah blah & 123456789 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}

\bigskip

\begin{NiceTabularX}{0.6\textwidth}{X[2]<{\pfill}@{\makebox[0.6em][c]{\textcolor{red}{.}}}>{\pfill}X}
    \toprule
    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456 \\
    Blah blah & 123456789 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to use `tabular` instead of `tabular*` and fix the width of (column 1 + dots), the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{W{c}{5cm} <{\dotfill} @{} c}
  \toprule
    Blah blah blah & 123 \\
    Blah blah blah blah blah & 123456\\
    Blah blah & 123456789\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]